# Getting another git repo tag without cloning it

Tags: github, tags

Can I get last tag or list of tags of another git repo from command line without cloning it?

actually I want to write a script that get the last tag of a repo to check if it different from mine I download it.

Comment: `git ls-remote`: this connects to another set of Git software on some other Git repository (same as fetch/clone) but after having that other Git software list out the other repository's refs (tags, branches, etc.), it disconnects, then shows you whatever subset of the refs it got. You'll need to write some code to work with its output though.

Comment: it is just it? or url is needed?

Comment: Note that this just gets you the *hash ID* of the tags (and any other refs you care to ask about). But the hash ID of a Git object *is* the object, in an important sense, so you can tell if you have that same object. There's no notion of "last" tag, so you'll need to check everything. (And yes, you must provide a URL, or a remote name that provides a URL. [Read the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote).)

Comment: oh God. OK. tnx. and do you think there was another easier way? like github api or wget or something else?

Comment: GitHub do have an API, but I didn't notice that you'd tagged this with `github`. Git and GitHub are very different: GitHub is a web hosting site. You can choose to make this work with *all* web hosting sites, or write a GitHub-specific thing, but if you mean to ask a GitHub-specific question, you probably should only use the [tag:github] tag. (Note that the SO tag [tag:tags] is almost certainly the wrong tag to use here.)

Comment: yes you are right sorry. actually I want to get the list of tags of a remote repo that is not for me